# Tensorflow batch training OutOfRangeError

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, outofrangeexception

```
Saving variables
Variables saved in 0.88 seconds
Saving metagraph
Metagraph saved in 35.81 seconds
Saving variables
Variables saved in 0.95 seconds
Saving metagraph
Metagraph saved in 33.20 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
Caused by op u'batch', defined at:
  File "ava_train.py", line 155, in <module>
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 872, in batch
name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 665, in _batch
dequeued = queue.dequeue_up_to(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 510, in dequeue_up_to
self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1402, in _queue_dequeue_up_to_v2
timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
```

> my code is here

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
     global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
     # process same as cifar10.distorted_inputs
     log_dir =  '../log'
     model_dir = '../model'
     max_num_epoch = 80
     if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
         os.makedirs(log_dir)
     if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
         os.makedirs(model_dir)
     num_train_example = len(os.listdir('../images/'))
     # Reads pfathes of images together with their labels
     image_list, label_list = read_labeled_image_list('../raw.txt')
     images = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
     labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=dtypes.int32)
     # Makes an input queue
     # input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], num_epochs=max_num_epoch, shuffle=True)
     input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels], shuffle=True)
     image, label = read_images_from_disk(input_queue)
     image_size = 240
     keep_probability = 0.8
     weight_decay = 5e-5
     image = preprocess(image, image_size, image_size, None)
     batch_size = 100
     epoch_size = 1000
     embedding_size = 128
     # Optional Image and Label Batching
     image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
```

This is the output of training an image classification model based on 20w images. I set *allow_smaller_final_batch=True* in *batch*. After some epochs the *OutOfRangeError* occured.

I don't know the reason and thanks for the help.

Comment: Would you have a piece of code we could use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added a piece of code to the question, but I don't know how to paste the whole code.

Comment: Would you be able to paste the part where you run the ops?

Comment: I am sorry i encountered a problem when trying to visit this page, the code is long so I refer the link [train.py](https://github.com/dieuroi/DAL/blob/master/train.py)

Answer (score 0):

Since you get a `OutOfRangeError` it could be that you are training for more epochs than `max_num_epochs`, which will result in the `slice_input_producer` throwing this exception.

One possible workaround would be to remove the `num_epochs=max_num_epochs` from your `slice_input_producer` since this will allow it to produce even after the maximum number of epochs has been reached.

Comment: thank you for your help. I run the code according to your suggestion but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have battled with this particular error for days. I finally found the cause. You are getting this error because your file is corrupted somewhere. Try running this code on another train and test data